# jQueryJavascript : "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]"

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `HTML` looks like

```
    <div class="queue_list">
        <div class="queue_item hide-item">
            <img class="thumbnail" />
            <p class="title"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My `jQuery` function looks like

```
$(function(){
    $('#queue').click(function(){
        $("#feature").load("templates/queue.html");
        var template = $('.queue_item').clone();
        if (localStorage['test'] == null ) {
            $('.queue_list').append(<p>You have not added any video to the queue yet</p>);
        } else {
            queue_list = JSON.parse(localStorage['queue']);
            for (var i = 0; i < queue_list.length; i++) {
                console.log(queue_list[i]);
            }
        }
    });
```

When I test this in `Firefox`, I see exception as

```
message "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]"
name    "NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS"
result  2153185289
__proto__   [unsupported: no toString() function in type object] { QueryInterface=QueryInterface(), initialize=initialize()}
```

my `localStorage['test']` is empty

What is that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You forgot to quote the HTML string inside the `append` apparently.

Comment: Happened to me when the element to animate was a HTML comment.